# JTable Mouse Listener Not Working Properly

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jtable, mouselistener

My JTable (jtblLot) Mouse Click Event not Fires some Times. Mainly on frequent Clicks

Below is the code for Mouse Click Event

```
 private void jtblLot_MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {       

    int row = jtblLot.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint()), currId = 0;
    int col = 3;

    lotId = jtblLot.getValueAt(row, col).toString();
    if (jtblLot.getValueAt(row, 1) != null) {
    sizeGrp_up = jtblLot.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
    } else {
    sizeGrp_up = "0";
    }

    if (jtblLot.getValueAt(row, 4) != null) {
    if (jtblLot.getValueAt(row, 4).toString().compareTo("") !=0)
    {
    currId = Integer.parseInt(jtblLot.getValueAt(row, 4).toString()) - 1;
    }
    } else {
    sizeGrp_up = "0";
    }

    cmbCurrency.setSelectedIndex(currId);
    jlblLotId.setText(lotId);

    // Sets Model For Another JTable(jtblLGP) In My Form Get Data From DB
    getLotGradePriceData();

    //On Click I get The Focus To The Clicked Cell
    int col_ = jtblLot.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
    jtblLot.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    jtblLot.changeSelection(row, col_, false, false);
    jtblLot.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(jtblLot.getCellRect(row, col_, true)));

}
```

Comment: A mmouse clicked event is generated when a mousePressed and mouseReleased event is received at the same point. So if the mouse moves even a pixel between those two events you don't get a mouseClicked. That is why you have the occasional problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to handle every click the I suggest you handle `mouseReleased` instead of `mouseClicked`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Sets Model For Another JTable(jtblLGP) In My Form Get Data From DB
getLotGradePriceData();
```

- [not good idea update Swing GUI this way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), you are block EDT untill JDBC Events ended,
- use `Runnable#Thread` (all output to the Swing GUI, its XxxModel must be wrapped into `invokeLater`) or `SwingWorker` as Workers Thread for this job,
- use [ListSelectioListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection) as easiest of possible ways
- maybe there are a few another issue, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, use local variables instead of JDBC events